# What is the difference between @login_required and @method_decorator(login_required) in django

Tags: python, django

I am new to django and  i am confused What is the difference  between  `@login_required` and `@method_decorator(login_required)` in Django, which one  we should use. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `@login_required` with function based views:

```
@login_required    
def my_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('hello')
```

You can use `@method_decorator(login_required)` with class based views,

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class MyView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'hello.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MyView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

however it's probably simpler to use `LoginRequiredMixin` instead:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'hello.html'
```

Answer (score 2):

The method_decorator decorator transforms a function decorator into a method decorator so that it can be used on an instance method.

login_decorator is a function decorator therefore it only can be use in view functions.

Source : [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class)